# Embedded Linux Device Driver Error Code 1-001a?

Tags: linux-kernel, camera, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have compile my camera driver and try to test it from my target board i.MX6Q 
I am facing with

> probe of 1-001a failed with error -16

Error when I look at the `dmesg | grep camera_name` , I think the 1-001a is refering to the device driver camera_name@1a . 
this  is my device driver

```
camera_name: camera_name@1a {
    compatible = "camera,camera_name";
    reg = <0x1a>;
    inck-name = "mclk";
    xvs-output-len = <8>;
    xclr-gpio = <&gpio1 6 1 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
    pwn-gpios = <&gpio1 6 1>;
    clock-names = "csi_mclk";
    DOVDD = <&reg_1p8v>;
    AVDD = <&reg_2p9v>;
    DVDD = <&reg_1p2v>;
    rst-gpios = <&gpio1 6 1>; /* xclr */    
    ipu_id = <0>;               
    csi_id = <0>;
    mclk = <37125000>;
    mclk_source = <0>;
    lanes = <4>;
};
```

But I couldnt understand what this error is saying ? Do you have any suggestion ? I couldnt find any information about it .

Thanks so much .

Best Regards.

Comment: Check *include/asm-generic/errno-base.h* for the code.

Answer (score 4):

> This error log `probe of 1-001a failed with error -16` informs us that :
>
> - The `.probe` function of
> - a device driver identified as `1-001a`
> - has return the error value [`-EBUSY`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L19)

The device-tree node mentioned in the question belongs to the device-driver.

To understand the reason for the above failure,

1. Start by locating the C file within the Linux kernel
   that implements the device driver for the above device.
2. Next Look for the function registered as the handler for ".probe" within the device driver.
3. Check under what conditions does it return `-EBUSY`.

---

[`errno-base.h`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h) contains the pre-defined convention of various common error numbers defined within the Linux kernel. Most functions in Linux kernel device drivers and the various Linux kernel sub-systems use these error codes as return values to signify error conditions.

Comment: thank you for your clear response, I look at the errno-base.h and find the -EBUSY  ` #define EBUSY  16 /* Device or resource busy */`   would it be about the choose the wrong gpio node or i2c node on the device tree ? And I would like to know how can we decide to choose which node depending on the device ? Is there any resource about that because I chose the xclr-gpio and pwn-gpios from the ov5640 device tree referance  because of that this error can be happend.

Comment: What you are guessing is a possiblity. A sure way to confirm it would be to read the probe function of the driver and check under what conditions it returns -EBUSY. If the driver returns EBUSY under more than one condition then you can try adding `printk()` statements in each of the conditional branches to confirm the flow within the probe function.

Comment: thanks for your advice , it help me to figure out at which part of code giving this error, I wrote pr_info(); function instead of printk(); but I think both are the same . Thanks so much .  I want to ask one more question . While we are writing the device tree node for example how to decide which gpios are should be selected is there any information or document about how to choose these gpşos or other things?

Comment: @Mustafa The choice of gpios would be determined by the hardware/board schematics that describe the connections between the peripheral camera sensor and the SoC.